# Need some assistance trying to parse this JSON response from our backend server

Tags: java, android, json

Currently working on an android app and I need help on how I can go about extracting the subfields within the responses field of this json object:

[image: pic of json object]

Currently I am doing the following to extract some of the other fields:

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response2);
 int id = json.getInt("id");
 String desc = json.getString("description");
 JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("owner");
 String username = json2.getString("userName");
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: if you checked the pic, im trying to extract the responses field, and the subfields within it, but not sure how

Comment: *"not sure how"* isn't a question, and give text not pictures.

Comment: It is an array, so use `getJSONArray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create logic to parse the data.  Every item from the JSON string is in the `JSONObject` you created with

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response2);
```

You're on the right track with what you're doing.  Just use the corresponding methods available in `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes to move through the object.

Start with the main object

```
{                              // <-- this is your main object (AKA JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response2))
    "id": 1,                   // to pull this id use json.getInt("id");
    "title": "some text here",  // to pull this title use json.getString("title");
    ...
    "owner": {                 // Here's the logic part, owner is itself, a JSON object. so now you must extract it and parse through it.
                               // to pull the "owner" JSON object, use JSONObject ownerObject = json.getJSONObject("owner");
        "userId": 1,           // Now use the ownerObject to pull it's values. ownerObject.getInt("userId");
        "userName": "TestingUser",  // to pull this userName use ownerObject.getString("userName");
        ...
    }
...
}
```

If it's an array, for example:

```
"someJSONArray": [{ "id": 1, "userName": "TestingUser1" }, { "id": 2, "userName": "TestingUser2" }]
```

then you would call:

```
JSONArray someJSONArray = getJSONArray("someJSONArray");
// Get each object from the array.
JSONObject object1 = someJSONArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject object2 = someJSONArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

or if the array contains a string, for example:

```
"someKey": [ 23, 435, 123, 6345, 123 ]
```

then you would call:

```
JSONArray someKeyArray = getJSONArray("someKey");
for (int i = 0; i < someKeyArray.length(); i++) {
    // Extract the value.
    int itemValue = someKeyArray.getInt(i);
}
```

The data is there, you just have to parse it.

Comment: I understand what you posted, but I get confused on how I can handle the responses, I believe its an array so should I go about it this way:

JSONArray someJSONArray = getJSONArray("responses");
JSONObject object1 = someJSONArray.getJSONObject(0);